# malloc allocate memory to a non-pointer type

Tags: c

How to allocate memory to a type which is not a pointer ?

I'd searched on the Internet and my textbook then got nothing about this.

All the example come from those like that

```
char *test;
test = malloc (STRING_SIZE * sizeof (char));
```

Which in pointer form, but what if a structure don't even need a pointer type to do that job as follow

```
struct _test_t {
  char *name;
  int flag;        //  <-- Here
};
```

or this is deprecated ?
What I can do is only declare as a pointer

```
...
int *flag;
...
```

then allocate as usual ?

```
struct _test_t *t;
t->flag = malloc (sizeof (int));
```

or any way out ?

Comment: why would you want to do that? If you allocate the memory for your struct, the int has it's memory already...

Comment: try t->flag =(int) malloc (sizeof (int));

Comment: @nikhilmehta, sizeof `int` may not be big enough to hold address, it depends upon the platform.

Comment: What are you even trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion about pointers and where things end up in memory. The fields of a struct are part of the struct's memory. In your case, the struct consists of a `char` pointer and an `int`. You don't need to allocate those separately once you have an instance of the struct, because they are already part of the struct.

```
struct _test_t *t = malloc(sizeof(struct _test_t));
t->flag = 123;
t->name = NULL;
```

Note that `name` doesn't point to anything interesting yet. Let's change that:

```
t->name = malloc(100);
```

Note the distinction between the *pointer* `name` and the memory that it points to. Only the pointer itself is part of the struct.

It is also possible to create an instance of the struct without using malloc, by allocating it on the stack:

```
struct _test_t t;
t.flag = 123;
t.name = malloc(100);
```

`t` is now allocated on the stack and will automatically be freed again when you leave the scope that it was declared in. However, `name` still points to memory on the heap which does *not* get freed with the struct, so you'd have to free that manually once you no longer need it.

Edit: You mention that you want to allocate memory to something that is not a pointer. That doesn't really make sense to me though. The function of `malloc` is to reserve some memory for your use and return a *pointer* to that memory. It needs to return the address of the memory that it has allocated because otherwise you wouldn't know where it is. And a pointer is really just an address value.

You can allocate space for an `int` with `malloc`, but you will get a pointer to an `int` that you have to use to access the actual `int`:

```
int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
*i = 123;
```

In C, there is no way to refer to that int directly without going through a pointer, which might be what you want. In C++ you could use a reference to refer to the int value directly:

```
int *i = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*i = 123;
int &j = *i;
cout << j << endl;
```

This would print "123", showing that `j` directly refers to the integer value. However, C does not have that feature, so you will always have to use the pointer.

Comment: Added some info about C++ references after checking that it compiles :)

Comment: **`t` is now allocated on the stack**  :  I think memory allocated for `t` is in heap and the variable itself `t` is allocated in stack.

Comment: In the example you quote from, `t` is the name for a contiguous piece of memory whose contents are interpreted as a pointer (`t.name`) and an int (`t.flag`). That memory resides in the stack. No part of `t` resides in the heap. When you access `t.name`, the pointer's value is read from the stack. The value of `t.name` happens to be a memory address in the heap, but I don't think that's what you're trying to get at.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` is used to allocate memory for objects whose **size is not known at compile-time**. That's why it returns a pointer, since it's the C representation for addresses (here of the memory area allocated on the heap).

Using malloc for another type does not make any sense, since their size are known (apart from templates but that's C++). Your `_test_t` struct (resp struct _test_t *t) is allocated resp. on the stack or the heap when declared, no need for you to manually allocate each members.

Comment: Actually it isn't; *struct _test_t *t;*